# .PID file gets deleted when running mysql.server start

Tags: mysql, pid

I installed mysql through `brew install mysql` and when I run `mysql.server start`, I get the error ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/User-Macbook-Pro.local.pid). After creating the .pid file, I run mysql.server start and get the same error. I've tried deleting the .err file but it just keeps removing my .pid file. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run these commands during install...

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db
```

also ensure that you're running mysql as the root user once you do have it installed...

`sudo mysql.server start`

Comment: 2021-08-02 13:40:46 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
2021-08-02 13:40:46 [ERROR]   The data directory needs to be specified.